# vb.net Use Pathstring Store Image Error: A generic error occurred in GDI+

Tags: vb.net, image, winforms

I have store and get image in database using pathstring.

When I choose new image to replace old image,  it prompt out error:

**1. A generic error occurred in GDI+**

Hope some expert can provide solution. Thank you.

```
            'Create path, prepare store in database 
            Dim concertID As String = lblConcert.Text.Substring(0, 8)
            Dim editName As String = concertID & ".jpg"
            Dim folder As String = "C:\Users\e-default\Desktop\csl\Uploaded Image"
            Dim pathString As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, editName)

            'Generate new concert
            Dim db As New MusicDataContext()
            Dim c = (From o In db.concerts
                     Where o.concert_id = concertID).FirstOrDefault

            c.name = txtEditName.Text
            c.description = txtEditDescription.Text
            c.time = cboEditTime.SelectedItem
            c.date = dtpEditDate.Value
            c.image = pathString
            db.SubmitChanges()

            'Save image to folder (Error found here, pcbEditImage is picture box)
            pcbEditImage.Image.Save(pathString)
```

Comment: [`Image.Save()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save) is an instance method, but you appear to be calling it like a `static`/`Shared` method (or maybe VB.NET guesses right that you meant `image`, not `Image`).  Still, the only thing you do with `image` prior to that is assign `pcbEditImage.Image` to it and then call `Dispose()` on that same instance, so `image` is referencing a disposed object.

Comment: 1) Don't dispose of the source Image before you use it. Do that as the last step (this is the main problem, here) 2) Don't use `image` as the Bitmap object name, VB.Net is not exactly case sensitive and gets confused sometimes, as you see in the last call: `Image.Save(pathString)`, you're using the Image class name, not the `image` local object. 3) `[Image].Save(pathString)` is saving the Image as PNG (the default ImageFormat), not as JPEG.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake. But it still prompt out error (A generic error occurred in GDI+) when I removing `pcbEditImage.Image.Dispose()`, `pcbEditImage.Image = Nothing` and `System.IO.File.Delete(c.image)`. I google search out that it cannot use same path for replace image. But I hope I can replace image and store in one same path for clean image management.

Comment: @newbie You could save it with a different name, delete the original, then rename the different name to the original name.

Comment: @AndrewMorton They system do not allow me to delete old image because it being used by other process. But anyway, thank you for the idea.

Comment: @newbie Please [edit] the question to *add* what your code is now after making the improvements recommended by Jimi.

Answer (score 0):

the problem its on save propiety try

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
Dim MyBitmap As New Bitmap(pcbEditImage.Image)
With SaveFileDialog1
.Filter = "JPG(*.JPG) |*.JPG"
.ShowDialog()
If .FileName.Length > 0 Then
Try
MyBitmap.Save(.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
.FileName = ""
Catch ex As Exception
MessageBox.Show(ErrSaveFile, TitleError, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End Try
End If
End With
End Sub
```

the clue is on

```
Dim MyBitmap As New Bitmap(pcbEditImage.Image)
```

and then

```
MyBitmap.Save(.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```